# Date formatting within react bootstrap table

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I am trying format the date in the column below as 'DD/MM/YYYY' and also the header row is not aligned with the data, how to fix this?

I am using the function

```
 function dateFormatter(cell: any) {
        var d = (moment(new Date('${cell}').toLocaleDateString()).format("DD/MM/YYYY"));
        return d;

    }
```

and in the TableHeaderColumn:

```
<TableHeaderColumn dataField='effectiveDate' dataSort={true} dataFormat={dateFormatter}  >Effective Date</TableHeaderColumn>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this - It works in my case

```
function dateFormatter(cell: any) {
    if (!cell) {
          return "";
    }
    return `${moment(cell).format("DD-MM-YYYY")? moment(cell).format("DD-MM-YYYY"):moment(cell).format("DD-MM-YYYY") }`;
}
```